# Calculate center point of layers sublayer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, layer

How to calculate center point of sublayers that was added to views sublayer? I want to add another layer as a subview to the layer's sublayer.
when I execute this statement it will return 0.
self.view.later sublayers[0].frame or
self.view.later sublayers[0].bounds

Comment: Looks like CGGeometry maybe useful for you (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html)

Comment: Can we retrieve width height info of layer's sublayer? I tried but everytime I get 0.0 values so

Comment: Yes, we can. CAlayer has properties frame and bounds (see documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/frame)

Comment: Ok I referred documentation and then tried it :) But it is returning point and  size as zero for sublayer

Comment: Probably there is no sublayer. Are you sure you need sublayer (instead of subview)?

Comment: yes. because on view layer I am drawing bezierpath as a layer, so whenever I tap on that layer area I need to draw another small bezierpath on the center of its parent layer.